# How to display a different alert when the text field is empty using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code, I want to display an alert saying to fill in if the textbox is empty after clicking the button:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Thank you for subscribing")
    }
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if` condition for different alerts for your purpose. As I understood, you need 2 alerts. 1. For if user clicks submit button and input is empty and 2. If the input value is not empty...

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = $('#inputId');

    if(input.length === 0){
        alert("Please correct the error");
    } else {
        alert("Thank you for subscribing");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can do the following:

```js
   function myFunction() {
  var inputData = document.getElementById('inputValue');
  if (inputData && inputData.value) {
      alert(inputData.value);
  } else {
      alert("fill in the data")
  }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputValue">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Subscribe</button>
```